# How to generate the Builder java class for your POJO

Tags: java, eclipse, builder

I have this pojo file that consists over 50 attributes. Creating a manual builder class can be error prone activity.

Is there a easy way to generate the builder class? for e.g. If you required to generate getter setters you would normally use eclipse `Source > Generate Getters and Setters` Is there a painless procedure to perform this?

Really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

You can annotate your class, for example:

```
@Data //generate getters and setters
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true) //self descriptive
@NoArgsConstructor //self descriptive
@AllArgsConstructor //self descriptive
```

Remark: it works only with Eclipse for now.

Comment: Out of interest, does Lombok allow you to specify whether you want to generate just getters? One of the beauties of the builder pattern is that it allows you to create immutable objects without having to have a mahoosive constructor. It would be a shame if Lombok undid that good work.

Comment: Yes, there is an option to generate just getters.

Answer (score 1):

I have just used [Practical macros](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/), within a **few minutes** of install from the market place, I could **generate** **constructors**, **getters** / setters, **toString**, **hashcode** and **equals** (basically chaining the standard eclipse commands) in a **single command**. Just what I was looking for and saved me loads of time. I can also see a lot more uses for it, well done to Earnst (the creator).

Answer (score 0):

Lombok has support for all the above requirement:

You can define all the getters and setters by adding @Data.
@Builder will make the class as builder.

There are more customisation also available for these annotations, you can find in their website https://projectlombok.org/

```
@Builder
@Data
public class Emails {
    @Builder.Default
    private String type = "work";
    private String value;
}
```